# adding a hover effect on a div tag using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

All I want to do is hide the class "col-a" and show "col-b" using jquery hover method but for some reason jquery is giving me some funky results.

here is the snippet

```js
$(".col-a").hover(function(){
    $(this).hide().next().show(1000)
    }, function(){
    $(".col-b").hide().prev().show(1000);
});
```

```css
.hide {
    display:none;
}
.col-a {
    height:200px;
    margin:10px;
    float:left;
    width:200px;
    background-color:yellow;
}
.col-b {
    height:200px;
    margin:10px;
    display:none;
    float:left;
    width:200px;
    background-color:yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-a">One</div>
<div class="col-b">Two</div>
<div class="col-a">One</div>
<div class="col-b">Two</div>
```

Here is a fiddle:

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/davadi/21fn2zg6/1/)

Comment: Why are there 2 divs with the same class next to eachother?

Comment: Like this https://jsfiddle.net/21fn2zg6/2/?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi you can use instead of `hover()` event just the `mouseover` for `col-a`  and then the `mouseout` for `col-b`. Try this:

```js
$(".col-a").mouseover(function(){
    $(this).hide();
    $(this).next(".col-b").fadeIn('100');
});
$(".col-b").mouseout(function(){
    $(this).hide();
    $(this).prev(".col-a").fadeIn('100');
});
```

```css
.hide {
    display:none;
}
.col-a {
    height:200px;
    margin:10px;
    float:left;
    width:200px;
    background-color:yellow;
}
.col-b {
    height:200px;
    margin:10px;
    display:none;
    float:left;
    width:200px;
    background-color:yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-a">One</div>
<div class="col-b">Two</div>
<div class="col-a">One</div>
<div class="col-b">Two</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Should I just avoid the hover method all together when working with block elements?

Comment: @user1119742 np glad to help you .... The block elements doesn't mean avoide the hover is just this specific situation, evaluate your actual behavior and wich event you need to trigger. When a is gone there is no more hover and generate the flicked effect so we need just the enter event then appears b and we just need the out.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="col-a">One</div>
<div class="col-b">Two</div>  



$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".col-a").hover(
       function(){
                 $(this).hide();
                 $('.col-b').show();
      },
        function(){
                 $(this).show(1000);
                 $('.col-b').hide();
     });
    });
```

Although you can get your result using mouseover and mouseout on .col-a and .col-b respectively

Answer (score -1):

Hi you can use this.

```
<script>
 $(".col-b").fadeOut("slow)
</Script>
```

Comment: It's a good idea to test your code before you post it - I've seen you post erroneous code twice today.  You're missing a quote.  It also doesn't answer the question.